# Chrome display bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a blog (designed with blogger) and there's one problem.

If I access the page directly: http://www.tips4design.com/2011/01/jq-sparks-particle-system.html everything is fine.

But if someone accesses the page by clicking the comments link: http://www.tips4design.com/2011/01/jq-sparks-particle-system.html#comments the content (below the navbar/adsense ads) is shifted up like 100px. This only seems to happen in chrome.

The problem is "worse" because when someone tries to write a comment in chrome after they click "Post Comment" the page will ask for captcha, but having the page shifted up the captcha input is messed up.

[image]
So, the question short: Why does chrome display the page differently when hashtag is added at the end of URL?

Comment: At first, I would fix the 105 errors and 30 warnings: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tips4design.com%2F2011%2F01%2Fjq-sparks-particle-system.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I see the same problem in Firefox 4

Comment: I guess it's not my problem blogger doesn't generate a valid code. And also, validating a code is irrelevant (google,yahoo, facebook, etc.. don't have valid code). I simply want to fix this problem without having to rewrite and clean the entire template... I've gone through the CSS and tried to fix this issue but I don't know why this 2 relative positioned, same z-index, distinct divs overlap...

Comment: div.main-outer seems to have a scrollTop of 23. Setting it to 0 gives back 23 pixels.

Comment: That's not the only problem, if you go to #comments link and try to write a comment, even if you can focus the textarea if you write something in it, the text will appear really slow... strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this CSS rule from your code:

```
.comments {
  margin-bottom: 200px;  //remove this rule
}
```

It seems to "push back" the comments pop-up after it is added dynamically to the page, thus pushing the content as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I do that using the javascript console { $('.comments').css('margin-bottom',0) } , the problem still exists. I really don't understand why the page is rendered different if there's a hashtag in the URL. And why the input is so buggy

Comment: I don't understand either, but why use jQuery to remove this style?
Can't you just remove the original style from where it's created? Removing this style in chrome fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Well, that seemed to work. Seems like deleting the style after the page is loaded is still making this bug persist. Thanks a lot! :*